# Google Recaptcha V3 spike in high risk assessment after V2 token creation

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, invisible-recaptcha

TLDNR version: Does creating a fallback V2 recaptcha token increase V3 "High Risk" flagging?

Was wondering if anyone else has run into this, but recently within the last couple weeks, Google Recaptcha V3 has flagged over 80% of daily traffic as "High Risk". However, this is effecting real users and just isn't a spike in malicious attempts.  Previously, a little under 30% of daily logins were flagged as high risk, but now it's around 85% and the people being marked as high risk are NOT bots.

What is really strange about this is that the start of these spikes started around the same time I created a V2 token for our site.  However, the code change has never been submitted, I merely created the V2 tokens on the admin console.  I'm having a hard time believing that simply creating this effected my V3's ability to determine bots, but could it?

There isn't much I can do here.  I would remove the V2 tokens on the Google Dashboard but they are already integrated in code changes awaiting a production push.

Comment: We are also experiencing an increased amount of low scores for legit users since the beginning of the month. I am wondering if something changed behind the scenes.